# bfs social network algorithm(graph algorithm) - hackerearth

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I tried this breadth first search practice problem from hackerearth[(link to problem)](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/algorithms/graphs/breadth-first-search/practice-problems/algorithm/social-networking-graph/). My code passed the sample test case. But I am missing something when it comes to the submission test cases.

I ran "my output" and the "test output" through a document distance program that i coded up(for the first submission input), and the distance was found to be ~ 0.52 (deg) [0 deg meaning the documents are exactly same, and 90 deg meaning the documents are entirely different]. This was done only to approximately measure how wrong i was. I need help to find what case(s) I'm failing to account for in my code.

**problem description:**

In a social networking site, people are connected with other people. The whole system appears as a giant connected graph. In this question, you are required to answer the total number of people connected at t nodes away from each other (t distance connectivity). For example: Two persons directly connected are at 1 distance connectivity. While the two persons having a common contact without having direct connectivity, are at 2 distance connectivity.

First line of input line contains, two integers n and e, where n is the nodes and e are the edges. Next e line will contain two integers u and v meaning that node u and node v are connected to each other in undirected fashion. Next line contains single integer, m, which is number of queries. Next m lines, each have two inputs, one as source node and other as a required t distance connectivity which should be used to process query.

Note: The index of nodes will be 0-based. The example and the test case shown is of 1-based index. For submitting the solution, use 0-based indexing.

**sample input:**

9 10

1 2

2 3

1 7

2 4

3 4

4 7

7 8

9 7

7 6

5 6

3

4 2

5 3

2 1

**output:**

4

4

3

**Explanation**
After creating the graph, there was 3 queries,

i. Source node: 4, and we have to find out total number of nodes at a distance of 2 from node 4.
1(4->2->1), 8(4->7->8), 9(4->7->9), 6(4->7->6) = 4

ii. Similarly as above

iii. Source node: 2, and we have to find out total number of nodes at a distance of 1 from node 2.
1(2->1), 4(2->4), 3(2->3) = 3

[link for input graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luzyj.png)

```
#social network bfs algorithm
from collections import deque
graph = {}
queries = []
def accept_values():
    #accept number of vertices and edges
    vertex_edge = [int(i) for  i in input().strip().split(" ")]
    #accept the edges for the undirected graph
    for i in range(vertex_edge[1]):
        edge = [int(i) for i in input().strip().split(" ")]
        try:
            graph[edge[0]].append(edge[1])
        except:
            graph[edge[0]] = [edge[1]]
        try:
            graph[edge[1]].append(edge[0])
        except:
            graph[edge[1]] = [edge[0]]
    #accepting the number of queries and the queries themselves
    number_of_queries = int(input())
    for i in range(number_of_queries):
        queries.append([int(i) for i in input().strip().split(" ")])
    #applying bfs on the (source, required distance) queries
    for query in queries:
        bfs(query)

def bfs(query):
    counter = 0
    q = deque()
    q.append(query[0])
    visited = {query[0] : True}
    distance = {query[0] : 0}
    while q:
        popped = q.popleft()
        for neighbour in graph[popped]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                visited[neighbour] = True
                #stop looking further because we have all the nodes at the required distance, i think
                if distance[popped] + 1 > query[1]:
                    for key in distance:
                        if distance[key] == query[1]:
                          counter +=1
                    print(counter)
                    return
                #keep going until we reach the required query distance
                else:
                    distance[neighbour] = distance[popped] + 1
                    q.append(neighbour)
    #prints 0 if there are no such nodes
    print(counter)
#calling function to accept values as per required format
accept_values()
```